# Script to combine single ip addresses to subnets

Tags: python, ip, subnet

I've ran into a problem which I cannot solve myself, not even with searching online.
I have a text file containing ~30000 individual ip addresses and subnets.
By looking into the file I can tell there are a lot of full /24 and /25 enumerated one ip by one, like:

x2.6x.121.0

x2.6x.121.1

x2.6x.121.2

x2.6x.121.3

...

x2.6x.121.255

and there are already bigger blocks:

xx2.24.32.0/24

xx2.24.7.0/23

How can I check all the lines and if there is a full /24 or /25 (or even /23 /22 etc) just write that /24 or /25 to a new file?
There is a software I need to feed this list, but I don't want to list ~30k /32 I want to combine them into bigger blocks if possible, but I need to be precise, so if there is even one IP missing from a block I cannot combine it, I need to list them by one by one with /32.

I tried to stick together different codes from searching online and even tried to enhance it with AI, but something is not working correctly. (my programming skills are *very* limited)

The latest code is this:

```
import ipaddress

def find_subnets(ip_list):
    subnets = {}
    for ip in ip_list:
        ip_obj = ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip)
        subnet = ipaddress.IPv4Network(ip_obj.exploded + "/24", strict=False)
        if subnet in subnets:
            subnets[subnet].append(ip)
        else:
            subnets[subnet] = [ip]

    return subnets

def write_subnets_to_file(subnets, output_file):
    with open(output_file, "w") as f:
        for subnet, ips in subnets.items():
            if len(ips) == 256:
                f.write(f"{subnet}\n")
            else:
                for ip in ips:
                    f.write(f"{ip}/32\n")

def main(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, "r") as f:
        ip_list = [line.strip() for line in f]

    subnets = find_subnets(ip_list)
    write_subnets_to_file(subnets, output_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = "input.txt"  # Replace with your input file name
    output_file = "output.txt"  # Replace with your output file name
    main(input_file, output_file)
```

but it still lists a lot of /32 and doesn't combine them to /24 (although there are a lot of /24 too finally). and there are even /23 and /22 in the input but only /24 in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The [`netaddr` package](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has a [`cidr_merge` function](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#netaddr.cidr_merge) that does what you want:

```py
In [5]: from netaddr import cidr_merge

In [6]: cidr_merge(['10.0.0.0', '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.4'])
Out[6]: [IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/30'), IPNetwork('10.0.0.4/32')]
```